# Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections

I faced a problem with a DataTable. When I run to client it throws an Exception and mentions the "in" in foreach.

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

This is the code:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in stStatusTable.Rows)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["st_id"]) == stStatus.st_id)
    {
        dr["st_id"] = Convert.ToInt32(dr["st_id"]) + 1;
        dr.AcceptChanges();

    }
    else
    {

        stStatusTable.Rows.Add(stStatus.st_id, stStatus.st_name, stStatus.RTime, stStatus.Total_Mark, stStatus.Completed);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What did this have to do with WCF? Removed the tag.

Comment: the project at all is build using wcf this is callback function

Comment: I'm not even sure what language this is in.

Comment: @ericx: is WCF _relevant_ to this question? Is this something that only happens if your project happens to be WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for-loop instead of an foreach loop.

However, be careful with the index when adding / removing items.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Becouse you are adding rows at the same time you are enumerating them..

You should add the rows to a second clean datatable, and after the loop, copy the rows from the new datatable to the original one.